# What kind of sentence is it called if there are no verbs in it, like this example?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> 'Thanks,' said Harry, picking up a packet of tiny black Pepper Imps. 'What's Hogsmeade like? Where did you go?'
>
> By the sound of it — everywhere. ***Dervish and Banges, the wizarding
>   equipment shop, Zonko's Joke Shop, into the Three Broomsticks for
>   foaming mugs of hot Butterbeer and many places besides***.
>
> 'The post office, Harry! About two hundred owls, all sitting on
>   shelves, all colour-coded depending on how fast you want your letter
>   to get there!'

I couldn't identify any verbs in the sentence in bold above. Does it have a verb in it? To me, it just provides a list of shops' names. I'm not sure if it is common in English. I've never seen this type of sentence before. Do we have a specific technical term to address it? Or if any kind of the guide when/where/how to use it?

Comment: It is a response to the question "Where did you **go**?" and so **went** is understood to be present:  "(went) everywhere" and what follows is a list of a places apposite *everywhere*.  You could replace that full stop after "everywhere" with a colon or dash, and the dash before *everywhere* with a comma. Those are  mere vagaries of punctuation.

Comment: I don't quite follow "by the sound of it" which is normally something said by a listener to a story, not the teller of the story, at least in my experience. *By the sound of it, **you** went everywhere*, not  *By the sound of it, **I** went everywhere*.  I've always heard "by the sound of it" used to mean "judging from what has been said" though I suppose it could mean "judging from what is about to be said".  Who is speaking those words?  Is that how those paragraphs are presented in the book?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yeah, I have read that part several times. I have a little doubt about it, but as a learner I can't decide anything and just try hard to follow new conventions.

Comment: Is it the narrator's (not the character's) voice intruding, summarizing the character's tale and describing the listener's (Harry's) reaction in advance of presenting the list of places visited? Is that Ron who is talking about the owls?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  This is the exact copy from the book. It's not the words from any characters.

Comment: If that is Ron talking about the owls (I haven't read the books) then it is as though the narrator is saying "By the sound of it, (Ron had gone) everywhere: Dervish and Banges, ... ".   The narrator is revealing the mind of Harry as he listened to the tale of the visit to Hogsmeade and heard those places listed.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yeah, that makes sence.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Can you also do me a favour to take a look at my another question I asked earlier about "plunged recklessly on"? Thanks!